# BLOCKS ARE NOT BRAKING

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I finished my house in minecraft and went back into Gamemode s. I tried to break my bed and it did not work. I tried to break other blocks such as wood and it would not break! I hope some one can help.

Comment: Please provide a video or more detailed description. There's a lot of things that could've gone wrong, from bug to lag or insufficient permissions.

Comment: "Game mode s", do you mean survival?  Are you on a server or single player?  Does it show the block breaking animation?  Does the block temporarily disappear and then reappear?

Answer (score 4):

### These are the reason I can think of that can cause this behavior

1. In case it's a simple bug you should try **restarting** your Minecraft.
2. You also might not be in the correct gamemode.  Confusion happens when you mix up using numbers and letters such as ***/gamemode 2*** and ***/gamemode a***.  Just to be safe you should try typing it all the way out like ***/gamemode survival***
3. It could also be that your Minecraft is running slow so it is
   causing the blocks to **lag**.  You can reduce this by going to your
   Video Setting and turning your Render Distance down, as well as
   changing your *Graphics* from *Fancy* to *Fast*, turning *Clouds:
   OFF*, and turning *Particles* to *Minimal*
4. Make sure you are ***holding down*** the attack button.  If you have
   played in creative a lot you may be used to instant breaking or maybe you are ***right clicking*** instead.  Just to make sure you
   should check under *controls* to see which button your
   *Attack/Destroy* is set to.